# Can I pay taxes using bill pay from my on-line checking account?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

It is US federal income tax time, and it seems I've developed an allergy to stamps & envelopes, and can't even find my checkbook. So I'm wondering, if I just use my bank's online "pay a bill" feature and send the money, but without the little payment voucher, will it be OK?

The catch is that I'm having an accountant do the efile, and they're not providing me with the direct deposit option.

Comment: Can you add the country tag to understand the geography and also specify what tax are you looking to pay online, personal income tax ?

Comment: How provincial of me, done.

Comment: Your accountant isn't allowing you to provide bank routing information?  Strange.   You could get a money order from your bank.

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't do this. There is a chance that your check could get lost/misdirected/misapplied, etc.  Then you would need to deal with the huge bureaucracy to try to get it fixed while interest and penalties pile up.

What you can do is have the IRS withdraw the money themselves by providing the rounting number and account number of your bank.  This should work whether is it a traditional brick and mortar bank or an online bank.

Comment: Exactly, just do a direct debit when you file a return

Comment: +1. Bill payments services suck. My wife works for a small utility, and these services probably screw up people's accounts a few dozen times a year in various ways.

Comment: @duffbeer703 Is this more or less than the number of people who forget to sign their check, fail to put the correct postage on their envelope, or have the USPS loose/misdirect their mail.  I don't know one way or another, but this would be the correct comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for the US, but I've completed direct tax payments via my online bank account (for business and personal) in two countries (South Africa and the UK).  I find it easier and with a better record that the transaction took place than any of the other methods available (including going directly into a tax office to pay by cheque).

Mail can go missing. Queueing in their offices takes hours and the result can still be misfiled (by them).  Ditto allowing them to do a pay run on your account - they can make a mistake and you'll have difficulty proving it.  A payment via my bank account gives me an electronic record and I can ensure all the details are correct myself.

In addition, in the UK, paying online gives you a good few months extra grace to pay.  Even in South Africa, online payments are given a few weeks grace over physical payments.  Their recognising that you paying electronically saves them processing time.

Answer (score 1):

And if you need to pay *business* taxes outside of the regular US 1040 form, you can use the IRS' Electronic Federal Tax Payment System (EFTPS). Basically, you enroll your bank accounts, and you can make estimated, penalty, etc. payments. The site can be found [here](https://www.eftps.gov/eftps/).

Comment: seems impossible to enroll

Comment: I think EFTPS is for businesses, not individuals